# Align UISwitch to align to center

Tags: swift, nslayoutconstraint, uiswitch

My swift code below is trying to get the uisiwtch to appear in the center of the screen. As you can see in my photo below. As You can see in the image below. The switch is taking up only a small part of the upper left of the screen. It does not look good.

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNVH7.png)

```
var soundSwitch = UISwitch()

NSLayoutConstraint.Activate[(
   soundSwitch.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: map.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
   soundSwitch.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: text.bottomAnchor, constant : 0),
   soundSwitch.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1/3, constant: 0),
   soundSwitch.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.07, constant: 0),
 )]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
soundSwitch.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: map.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
```

with

```
soundSwitch.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: map.centerXAnchor, constant: 0),
```

Btw don't forget

```
soundSwitch.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Also it's preferred to remove both

```
soundSwitch.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1/3, constant: 0),
soundSwitch.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.07, constant: 0),
```

As the switch won't scale